# Javascript DataTables warning, Requested unknown parameter 'Id' for row 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to fill a Datatable using ajax :

Also, I can get all datas in controller and i am returning Json from there. There is no any problem in controller. Just I can't fill datatable.

[image]

My javascript code in below :

This is my function

```
function createDatatable(setting) {
    var actionsColumn = {
        sortable: false,
        searchable: false,
        class: 'text-center',
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="/' + setting.controller + '/Edit/' + row[setting.primaryKey] + '" title="Düzenle"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="/' + setting.controller + '/Delete/' + row[setting.primaryKey] + '" title="Sil"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>';
        }
    };
    if (setting.hasCostumActionsColumn === undefined || setting.hasCostumActionsColumn == false) {
        setting.columns.push(actionsColumn);
    }
    if (setting.defaultSortingColumn === undefined) {
        setting.defaultSortingColumn = 0;
    }
    if (setting.defaultSorting === undefined) {
        setting.defaultSorting = "desc";
    }
    if (setting.queryString === undefined) {
        setting.queryString = "";
    }
    var url = '/' + setting.controller + '/' + setting.action;
    if (setting.queryString != undefined && setting.queryString != "") {
        url += '?' + setting.queryString;
    }
    var table = $('#' + setting.tableId).DataTable({
        info: false,
        dom: '<"toolbar">frtip',
        deferRender: true,
        fnInitComplete: function () {
            $("#table1_paginate").remove();
            handlePaging();
            $('#next-btn').on('click', function () {
                table.page('next').draw('page');
                updateCurrentPageInput();
            });
            $('#previous-btn').on('click', function () {
                table.page('previous').draw('page');
                updateCurrentPageInput();
            });
            $("#goto-page").on('click', function () {
                var page = parseInt($("#pagination-current-page").val());
                if (page < 1) {
                    page = 1;
                } else if (page > table.page.info().pages) {
                    page = table.page.info().pages;
                }
                var index = page - 1;
                table.page(index).draw('page');
                updateCurrentPageInput();
            });
            $("#pagination-row-count").change(function () {
                table.page.len($("#pagination-row-count").val()).draw();
                updateCurrentPageInput();
            });
        },
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {
            updateCurrentPageInput();
        },
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        deferRender: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "Tümü"]],
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": document.querySelector('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value
            },
            data: function (data) {
                let additionalValues = [];
                data.AdditionalValues = additionalValues;
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        columns: setting.columns,
        columnDefs: setting.columnDefs,
        order: [setting.defaultSortingColumn, setting.defaultSorting]
    });
    $("#filter-table").on('click', function () {
        $(".table-filter").each(function (k, item) {
            var index = $(item).data('index');
            var val = $(item).val();
            if (val != "") {
                table.column(index + ':visible').search(val);
            } else {
                table.column(index + ':visible').search('DisableSearch');
            }
        });
        table.draw();
    });
    $("#clear-filter-table").on('click', function () {
        document.getElementById("filter-form").reset();
        $(".table-filter").each(function (k, item) {
            var index = $(item).data('index');
            table.column(index + ':visible').search('');
        });
        table.draw();
    });
    $(".table-title").prependTo($("#table1_wrapper"));
    function updateCurrentPageInput() {
        console.log('table pager');
        var currentPage = table.page() + 1;
        $("#pagination-current-page").val(currentPage);
        if (table.page() === 0) {
            $('#previous-btn').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#previous-btn').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        if (table.page.info().pages === currentPage) {
            $('#next-btn').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#next-btn').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        $("#pagination-current-page").prop('max', table.page.info().pages);
        $("#table-info-div").html(`Toplam ${table.page.info().pages} sayfanın ${table.page() + 1}. sayfasındasınız. Toplam ${table.page.info().recordsTotal} kayıt bulunmaktadır.`);
    }
    function handlePaging() {
        $('div.toolbar').html(`
                <span id="table-info-div">Toplam2 ${table.page.info().pages} sayfanın ${table.page() + 1}. sayfasındasınız. Toplam ${table.page.info().recordsTotal} kayıt bulunmaktadır.</span>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button id="previous-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-sm paginate_button previous" style="margin-right:5px">< Önceki</button>
                    <input type="number" id="pagination-current-page" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" step="1" style="padding:5px; width:50px;margin-right:5px;" />
                    <button id="goto-page" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px">Git</button>
                    <button id="next-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-sm paginate_button next" style="margin-right:5px">Sonraki ></button>
                    <div class="kayitSayisi">
                        <select id="pagination-row-count" class="form-control">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
        $("#pagination-current-page").prop('max', table.page.info().pages);
        if (table.page() === 0) {
            $('#previous-btn').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#previous-btn').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        if (table.page.info().pages === 1) {
            $('#next-btn').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#next-btn').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Here, I am calling the function :

```
createDatatable({
    tableId: 'table1',
    controller: 'User',
    action: 'LoadTable',
    columns: [
        {
            data: "Id",
            name: "eq",
            visible: true,
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            data: "FirstName",
            name: "co",
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            data: "LastName",
            name: "co",
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            data: "UserName",
            name: "co",
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            data: "Email",
            name: "co",
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            sortable: false,
            class: 'text-center',
            searchable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" href="/User/ChangePassword/' + row["Id"] + '" title="Şifre Değiştir"><i class="icon-lock"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="/User/Edit/' + row["Id"] + '" title="Düzenle"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="/User/Delete/' + row["Id"] + '" title="Sil"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>';
            }
        }
    ],
    primaryKey: "Id",
    hasCostumActionsColumn: true
});
```

Update :
I added html code :

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="card-group-control card-group-control-right">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h6 class="card-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed text-default" href="#filter-collapse" style="display:block">Filtrele</a>
                </h6>
            </div>

            <div id="filter-collapse" class="collapse">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form id="filter-form">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-12">Id</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control table-filter" data-index="0" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-12">Adı</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control table-filter" data-index="1" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-12">Soyadı</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control table-filter" data-index="2" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-12">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control table-filter" data-index="3" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-12">E-Posta</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control table-filter" data-index="4" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" id="filter-table">Listele</a>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear-filter-table">Temizle</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-title">Kullanıcılar</div>
            <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable-ajax datatable-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th >Id</th>
                        <th data-priority="1">Adı</th>
                        <th data-priority="2">Soyadı</th>
                        <th>Kullanıcı Adı</th>
                        <th>E-posta</th>
                        <th style="width: 210px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the json look like?

Comment: and the html for the table

Comment: I added just now, please check it @KScandrett